# KnockoutJS Inheriting functionality via ko.utils.extend

Tags: javascript, inheritance, knockout.js

I'm trying to inherit functionality from a parent view model to a child view model like so:

```
function ParentVM() {
    var self = this;

    self.MyFunc = function () {
        console.log(self.SomeVar);  // this logs "undefined"
    }
}

function ChildVM() {
    var self = this;
    ko.utils.extend(self, new ParentVM());

    self.SomeVar = "hello";
}
```

However, when `MyFunc` is called, `SomeVar` is undefined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case anybody is struggling with this, I found a solution outside of the KnockoutJS framework:

```
function ParentVM() {
    var self = this;

    self.MyFunc = function () {
        console.log(self.SomeVar);
    }
}

function ChildVM() {
    var self = this;
    ParentVM.apply(self); // this instead

    self.SomeVar = "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you would want to use `this` instead of `self` in `MyFunc`. The way it is written now, `MyFunc` will always use `self` that is set to the value of `this` that is the new `ParentVM` instance.

Comment: Hey Ryan, fan of your blog ;). I tried that and it wasn't working - when I would log `this`, it would say it was the Parent's Parent view model..strange..

Comment: your answer is a fine choice too, as it would run the code from `ParentVM`, but not create a new instance and use your `ChildVM` as `this`.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/X5YpA/ with `this`, but the way that you did it is a good choice too. If you do get into using the prototype, then you will have to do some additional work to ensure that those functions/properties are available.

Comment: So strange, I see it working in your fiddle and event when I add a GrandParentVM it still seems to work, but in my app (which is much more complex and must have something else going on), it's not working..I'll see if I can cut to the bottom of this..

Comment: I think the bottom line is the context of `this` is getting screwed up in my app somehow. I know javascript can get funky with `this`

Comment: Ryan, just wanted to say thank you, for your your helpful answers.

Comment: btw, any ideas why self in parent viewmodel does not have child properties if executed outside a method ? for instance: http://jsfiddle.net/X5YpA/1/